# regex ensure that a string only contains pipes, numbers and /or commas,

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I assure myself that a string only contains JUST numbers and pipe (or also) commas, charcters? EG: all of the characters are only numbers and pipes or numbers, commas and pipes only

```
EG: 
1|2,2|3    = true
1|2        = true
bob        = false
bob|yes,no = false
```

this is as far as I have got so far

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9|]|[0-9,|]+$/', $str)){ 
   //if all of the characters are only numbers and pipes or numbers, commas and pipes only

}
```

Comment: @Itay, No need to escape `|` inside the `[]` because special character lose their meaning inside `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following:

```
function ensure($str) {
    return (bool) preg_match('/^[\d|,]+$/', $str);
}

var_dump(ensure('1|2,2|3'));
var_dump(ensure('1|2'));
var_dump(ensure('16|2'));
var_dump(ensure('bob'));
var_dump(ensure('bob|yes,no'));
var_dump(ensure(''));
```

prints

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Comment: at the moment I think numbers greater than 10 don't work EG: 16|2, possibly that was what was wrong with my original, these numbers have no ceiling

Comment: @user26676, It works as expected. Is there any surrounding spaces?

Comment: no, you are right I can see the preg is working on ideone (nice site btw, new to me!) I'll have to dig into my code

Comment: it works there was a typo in a `$_request` variable name all along too